# Запретить смену Background в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Нужно запретить в ubuntu смену пользователем фонового изображения. Желательно через Dconf.

Comment: это ж не *ms/windows*.

Comment: Зачем? о_О​​​​​

Comment: Нужно юзерам поставить массово фон с инфой, чтоб не меняли) Нашел вариант с обрезкой прав на каталоги - но хотелось бы универсальности.

Answer (score 3):

1. Создаём профиль пользователя:

`/etc/dconf/profile/user`

```
user-db:user
system-db:local
```

2. Создаём файл с пользовательскими настройками:

`/etc/dconf/db/local.d/01-background`

```
picture-uri='file:///usr/local/share/backgrounds/wallpaper.jpg' # здесь путь к вашим обоям
picture-options='scaled'
primary-color='000000'
secondary-color='FFFFFF'
```

3. Создаём директорию, в которой будет храниться список ключей `dconf`, которые надо блокировать:

`mkdir -p /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks`

4. Создаём файл:

`/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/00_default-wallpaper`

```
/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri
/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options
/org/gnome/desktop/background/primary-color
/org/gnome/desktop/background/secondary-color
```

5. Обновляем настройки `dconf`:

`dconf update`

6. Чтобы настройки применились, нужно перезагрузиться или перелогиниться.